# jmeter - dynamically adding header fails post 2nd iteration

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to add uri's from csv file and run functional tests. So basically the test plan is described below. For each http request getting triggered from jmeter, using preprocessor I am  trying to add or clear header details in header manager. For first 2 lines(requests) in csv the requests are fired successfully, but for third url the header clearing gives error.

```
Test plan-|            
          |->thread-|
                    |->while loop-|
                                  -> CSV file
                                  -> http request
                                     -> header manager
                                     -> beanshell pre processor
                     -> result tree

import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;

log.info("--------------------->>>> BEFORE 1 CLEARING HEADER");
if (ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().size() != 0){
    log.info("--------------------->>>> BEFORE 2 CLEARING HEADER");
    sampler.getHeaderManager().clear();
    log.info("--------------------->>>> AFTER 1 CLEARING HEADER");
}

if(!vars.get("LABEL").equals("login")) {
    log.info("--------------------->>>> IN iF COND LABEL != LOGIN");
    if (vars.get("environment").equals("gateway")) {
        log.info("--------------------->>>> ADDING HEADER <!LOGIN> <environment = gateway>"); 
        ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Accept", "application/json"));
        ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Content-Type", "application/json"));
         ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authentication",vars.get("authCode")));
         ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization", "Bearer 4b6e13b4dfc3187de6c2b762c84d9196"));
         sizeHeader = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().size();
         log.info("==================>>>> size of header after ADDING HEADER <!LOGIN> <environment = gateway> <" + sizeHeader + ">");
    } else {
        log.info("--------------------->>>> ADDING HEADER <!LOGIN> <environment != gateway>");
        ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Accept", "application/json"));
        ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Content-Type", "application/json"));
        ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization",vars.get("authCode")));
        sizeHeader = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().size();
         log.info("==================>>>> size of header after ADDING HEADER <!LOGIN> <environment = !gateway> <" + sizeHeader + ">");
    }
} else {
    log.info("--------------------->>>> ADDING HEADER <LOGIN> <environment = gateway>"); 
    ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Accept", "application/json"));
    ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    sizeHeader = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().size();
    log.info("==================>>>> size of header after ADDING HEADER <LOGIN> <environment = gateway> <" + sizeHeader + ">");
}
```

-------------------------- LOG FILES ARE FOLLOWS --------------------------

```
2017-06-22 20:37:57,049 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2017-06-22 20:37:57,050 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2017-06-22 20:37:57,056 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2017-06-22 20:37:57,060 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2017-06-22 20:37:57,061 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2017-06-22 20:37:57,061 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2017-06-22 20:37:57,061 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
2017-06-22 20:37:57,066 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2017-06-22 20:37:57,066 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2017-06-22 20:37:57,067 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2017-06-22 20:37:57,067 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\projects\testFrag\apiTest.csv
2017-06-22 20:37:57,070 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: --------------------->>>> BEFORE 1 CLEARING HEADER
2017-06-22 20:37:57,073 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: --------------------->>>> ADDING HEADER <LOGIN> <environment = gateway>
2017-06-22 20:37:57,073 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: ==================>>>> size of header after ADDING HEADER <LOGIN> <environment = gateway> <2>
2017-06-22 20:37:57,889 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: --------------------->>>> BEFORE 1 CLEARING HEADER
2017-06-22 20:37:57,889 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: --------------------->>>> BEFORE 2 CLEARING HEADER
2017-06-22 20:37:57,889 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: --------------------->>>> AFTER 1 CLEARING HEADER
2017-06-22 20:37:57,891 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: --------------------->>>> IN iF COND LABEL != LOGIN
2017-06-22 20:37:57,891 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: --------------------->>>> ADDING HEADER <!LOGIN> <environment = gateway>
2017-06-22 20:37:57,892 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: ==================>>>> size of header after ADDING HEADER <!LOGIN> <environment = gateway> <4>
2017-06-22 20:38:00,050 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: --------------------->>>> BEFORE 1 CLEARING HEADER
2017-06-22 20:38:00,050 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval     Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;  log.info("-------------- . . . ''
2017-06-22 20:38:00,050 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval       Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;  log.info("-------------- . . . ''
2017-06-22 20:38:01,466 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stop Thread seen for thread Thread Group 1-1, reason: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of file:C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\projects\testFrag\apiTest.csv detected for CSV DataSet:CSV Data Set Config configured with stopThread:true, recycle:false
2017-06-22 20:38:01,467 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2017-06-22 20:38:01,468 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
```

**EDIT 1**

Feel that the error might be in "ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().size()" statement when it executes third time. Did try the code with try and catch statements. Displays as null pointer error.

Also the while loop is controlled by CSV data set where i have set "STOP thread on EOF" to "true".

Comment: my first suspicion will be that `vars.get("LABEL")` may return null in which case `vars.get("LABEL").equals("login")` will throw an exception. Safer way is always call equals on constant string: `"login".equals(vars.get("LABEL"))` - never fails with exception, even if `vars.get` is null

Comment: Otherwise you need to get to the bottom of `ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method...` BeanSHell is quite terrible in publishing errors, you might be able to see the line it is failing at if you look at the log. If not, disable portions of the script and find what actually fails. Not the best debugging options there unfortunately

Comment: Feel that the error might be in "ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().size()" statement when it executes third time. 

Did try the code with try and catch statements. Displays as null pointer error.

Comment: Also the while loop is controlled by CSV data set where i have set "STOP thread on EOF" to "true".